# Conditionally include a field (_id or other) in mongodb project aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, projection

I've got a mongodb aggregation pipeline with a $project stage and I'd like to include certain fields only if conditions are met.  Specifically, I'd like to exclude the _id in one condition and include a second field 'second_id' in the other condition.

I know that it's not possible (yet) to exclude fields from a mongodb $project, but is it possible to conditionally include them?

Is there a way to conditionally exclude the _id field?  It accepts a 0 or 1, but what if I want to determine that 0 or 1 based on an if statement.  How would this be done?

Pseudocode for _id:

```
$project: { _id: { $ifNull: [ "$user_id", 0 ] } }
```

The main use of this would be to use the doc.user_id as the result _id, or allow mongodb to create a new autoincrement _id if that user_id is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way currently to do this within the $project stage, but you can use the $redact stage to remove the field conditionally (i.e. you set the value to 0 like you are doing in your example.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  ... matching and stuff ...
  {$project: { _id: { $ifNull: [ "$user_id", 0 ] } }},
  {$redact: {
  {$cond: {
    if: { $eq: [ "$user_id", 0 ] },
    then: '$$PRUNE',
    else: '$$DESCEND'
  }}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a trick for this one:

`"_id": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$user_id", null]}, "$nonExistinField", "$user_id"]}`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this was not doable when the question was asked, but now it is.

There is a way to conditionally include/exclude a particular field in `$project` stage.

This can be achieved using `$cond` to evaluate your condition, and then return either `'$true'` or `'$false'`

```
{
  myConditionalField:{$cond:{
    if:{
      $eq:['$some_field','some_value']
    },
    then:'$false',
    else:'$true'
  }}
}
```

Here, the field `myConditionalField` will be projected only if the value of `some_field` from previous stage matched `some_value`.

**NOTE:** Its assumed here that `myConditionalField` already exists from a previous stage. If it doesn't, then the `else` should be `$some_field` or whatever field you want to be projected.

Comment: I guess in the else block maybe it's `$some_field ` rather-than `$true`

Comment: @srinivasy this goes in the `$project` stage. If `myConditionalField` already exists from a previous stage, all you need is `$true`. If it doesn't, then it should be what you specified.