# Omitting part of a mongo array when it has a specific value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a json array structured like this:
`{
    "properties": [{
            "name": "ok",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "ok_aswell",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "ok_aswell",
            "value": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "get_rid",
            "value": 2
        }
    ]
}`

I want my query to return everything except the "get_rid" record:
`{
    "properties": [{
            "name": "ok",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "ok_aswell",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "ok_aswell",
            "value": 2
        }
    ]
}`

I tried the suggestions from here: [Conditionally include a field (_id or other) in mongodb project aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933221/conditionally-include-a-field-id-or-other-in-mongodb-project-aggregation) , however they didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $filter in projection aggregate

```
{$project:{
  properties:{
      $filter: {
                 input: "$properties",
                 as: "item",
                 cond: {$ne: ["$$item.name","get_rid"]}
               } 
  }
}}
```