# Project a field based on condition MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, fastapi

My schema in MongoDB looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "be9e9198-86ab-456e-97e1-f1039cb07b59",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "user": {
    "name": "john2",
    "surname": "doe2",
    "email": "123.abcd@gmail.com",
    "phone": "+012345678912",
    "age": 20,
    "gender": "male",
    "nationality": "smth",
    "universityMajor": "ENGINEERING",
    "preferences": null,
    "highPrivacy": false,
  }
  (Other stuff)
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I am trying to include the field `user.phone` only when `user.highPrivacy` is set to False. Otherwise, I want to exclude the field.

For example, given the above user, I should return the phone number. But if `user.highPrivacy` was later set to True, it should not include it.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
dbConnection.aggregate([
            {"$match" : 
                {"_id": userId, "isDeleted" : False} 
            },
            {
                "$project" : {
                    "postings" : 0,
                    "starredPostings" : 0, 
                    "user.timestamp" : 0, 
                    "user.phone" : { "$cond" : [{"$eq": ["$user.highPrivacy", True]}, 0, "$user.phone"] },
                }
            },
            ])
```

This keep giving me the error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Invalid $project :: caused by :: Cannot use expression other than $meta in exclusion projection
```

But the answers that are here:

- [Conditionally include a field (_id or other) in mongodb project aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933221/conditionally-include-a-field-id-or-other-in-mongodb-project-aggregation?rq=1)
- [Project different fields based on different condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635878/project-different-fields-based-on-different-condition)
- https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/mongodb-project-condition-how-to-use-project-with-a-condition-469

are using the same projection as me, or at least I think they are.

So where exactly is the issue in my aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- if you want the field to be calculated from expression and removed you don't make it be `0` you use the system variable `$$REMOVE`
- you can use `$project` or `$set` the bellow does keeps or removes phone based on `highPrivacy` field

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=636e6ce9424f6130d7f12162)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"user.phone": 
     {"$cond": 
       [{"$eq": ["$user.highPrivacy", true]}, "$$REMOVE", "$user.phone"]}}}])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [$cond](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) stage and the [$$REMOVE](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.REMOVE) keyword.

See example in playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/x09lSOojjiY

Example collection data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "user": {
      "name": "john2",
      "phone": "+012345678912",
      "highPrivacy": false
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "user": {
      "name": "john2",
      "phone": "+012345678912",
      "highPrivacy": true
    }
  }
]
```

Aggregation query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "isDeleted": false
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "isDeleted": 1,
      "user.name": 1,
      "user.highPrivacy": 1,
      "user.phone": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [ "$user.highPrivacy", true ]
          },
          then: "$user.phone",
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "user": {
      "highPrivacy": false,
      "name": "john2"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "isDeleted": false,
    "user": {
      "highPrivacy": true,
      "name": "john2",
      "phone": "+012345678912"
    }
  }
]
```